# QComboBox AdjustToContents changing height

Tags: qt, pyqt, qcombobox, qtgui

I'm trying to set a `QComboBox` to have expanding height, but adjusting to contents length.

The combo is created like this:

```
self.dataentrycombo = QComboBox()
self.dataentrycombo.setIconSize(QSize(48,48))
self.dataentrycombo.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
self.dataentrycombo.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QComboBox.AdjustToContents)
self.dataentrycombo.setModel(self.dataentrymodel)
```

After I populate my model, the size adjusts, but the height is smaller than the toolbar that the combobox lives in:

[image]

If I change my main window size then it will expand fully:

[image]

I have tried using `QComboBox.AdjustToMinimumContentsLengthWithIcon`, but then it just looks like this:

[image]

My model items are created like this:

```
    item = QStandardItem(QIcon(form.icon), form.icontext)
    item.setData(form, Qt.UserRole + 1)
    self.dataentrymodel.appendRow(item)
```

Extra Info:

- Qt: 4.7
- Windows 7 and 8

Comment: I replicated your example as closely as I could, but I cannot reproduce this behaviour. For me, setting the size policy is enough to expand the height (otherwise, the combo is centred vertically in the toolbar). So I think a more complete is example needed (unless there is some version- or platform-specific issue involved).

Comment: @Nathan W, I faced the same problem a few months ago, after trying hard to fix it, I finally found a solution that fixed the problem. I just called `adjustSize()` on the widget that was not expanding. after setting the *model* call `adjustSize()` on `QComboBox` object. I think this should solve your problem. If it does not work for you, try calling the same method on the widget then contains `combobox`

Comment: and if it stil does not work, resize the window to it's current size. `self.resize(self.size())` (this is a hack to adjust the children of a window)

Comment: Tried all those things and nothing seemed to work.

Comment: @NathanW. I don't think it's going to be possible to help without seeing all code used to construct the toolbar. It might also be useful to know the platform you're on, and the version of Qt you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it using:

```
    self.dataentrycombo.setMinimumHeight(self.projecttoolbar.height())
```

It's a bit of a dirty hack but it works OK for now.